# I'd like to use a common label for different @inproceedings entrances

Tags: bibtex

Is it possible to have a list of entrances from the same conference where I use one label for the paper and another for the conference? So, when I want to cite all the papers presented in that conference, I use only one label?

Example:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{smith2006,4thconference 
author={M Smith}, 
title={How to do things}, 
booktitle={4th Conference on doing things}, 
year={2006}, 
address={Tokio} } 
@INPROCEEDINGS{doe2006,4thconference 
author={J Doe}, 
title={Analysis of things done}, 
booktitle={4th Conference on doing things}, 
year={2006}, 
address={Tokio} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, put the names in a `\def`, and use that in the `\cite` argument.  EDITED to provide self-compiling example.

In this example, `goosens93` and `segl03` are the paper labels, whereas `\confrefs` is the conference reference label, invoking all of the individual papers from the conference in one fell swoop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@ARTICLE{segl03,
        AUTHOR  = "Segletes, S. B. AND Walters, W. P.",
        TITLE = {Extensions to the Exact Solution of the Long-Rod
                 Penetration/Erosion Equations},
        JOURNAL = "IJIE",
        YEAR    = "2003",
        VOLUME  = "28",
        PAGES   = "363--376"}
\end{filecontents}
\def\confrefs{goossens93, segl03}
\begin{document}
In these refs\cite{\confrefs}\ldots

Later, also referencing\cite{\confrefs}, more stuff.

But I can also cite just the paper\cite{segl03}.
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is different from what I was thinking, but does the job perfectly. Thank you very much!